# R replacing a column from a data frame with a row from another data frame

Tags: r

I want to replace the first column of A with the first row of B. For example:

```
A <- data.frame(matrix("a", 4, 4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> A
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  a  a  a  a
2  a  a  a  a
3  a  a  a  a
4  a  a  a  a

B <- data.frame(matrix("b", 4, 4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> B
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  b  b  b  b < Take this row
2  b  b  b  b
3  b  b  b  b
4  b  b  b  b
```

I want A to become:

```
> A
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  b  a  a  a
2  b  a  a  a
3  b  a  a  a
4  b  a  a  a
   ^
replace it with this column
```

I tried:

```
A[, 1] = B[1, ]
```

But I get the following warning message:

```
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 1, value = list(X1 = "b", X2 = "b",  :
  provided 4 variables to replace 1 variables
```

Comment: @Sotos No, I want to replace a column from A by a row from B. What you suggest is to replace o column of A by a column of B.

Comment: Yes I didnt read it all the way through :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `R` does not drop the dimension when there is just one row left (while it does when there is just one column).

From `?extract.data.frame`:

> **drop**: logical. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension. The default is to drop if only one column is left, but not to drop if only one row is left.

You can see that doing:

```
A[, 1]
# [1] "a" "a" "a" "a"
```

The result is a `vector`

and

```
B[1, ]
#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  b  b  b  b
```

the result is still a `data.frame`

You need to `unlist` the result:

```
A[, 1] = unlist(B[1, ])
A
#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  b  a  a  a
#2  b  a  a  a
#3  b  a  a  a
#4  b  a  a  a
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work, without changing row / col names:

```
A[, 1] = t(B)[,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
A[, 1] = t(B[1, ])
```

Comment: This almost works. However, I'd like to only change the cell values, without affecting the columns' or rows' names. Idealy, it should also work for data frame with different column and row names.